# Display the first 3 occurrences of a specific word from the file

Tags: grep

What command would be used to display the first 3 occurrences of the word `set` from the file `/boot/config-4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64`?

Comment: This seems oddly specific - is it a homework task?

Comment: No, I'm just new to Linux, and I feel like I'm doing it wrong. Just looking through config files and I'm not sure what directory or anything I'm supposed to be in.

Comment: Do you want the first three occurrences or the first three _lines_ where the word occurs? For example, if you have `set foo set` on one line, the `grep` solution provided by steeldriver, would count that as one occurrence, not two. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep`

```
grep -Fwm3 'set' /boot/config-4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64
```

where the options are

- `-F`      treat the search pattern as a fixed string (not strictly necessary here, since there are no special characters in the pattern `set`)
- `-w`      match whole words
- `-m3`     stop reading after 3 matched lines

Note that this will find the first three *lines* matching `set`. If you have multiple occurrences of `set` on the same line, they will all count as one occurrence, not multiple.

Comment: What directory would I put it in?

Comment: @MichaelMunroe it's just a command to be run in a terminal - you don't need to put it anywhere

Comment: IT doesnt work thats why I'm confused, says there is no file

Comment: @MichaelMunroe well the file `/boot/config-4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64` will likely only exist on your system if 4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1 is your current (or recent) kernel version. If you want to search your current kernel config, you could use `grep -Fwm3 'set' /boot/config-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 0):

To check if a file contains at least 3 words `set`:

```
gawk '{ count+=gsub(/\<set\>/, "", $0) }
    count>=3 { print "found at least 3 words <set>"; x="found"; exit }
END{ if(x!="found") print "only " count " words <set> seen" }' infile
```